# Install ColdFusion 8 on Snow Leopard?

Tags: coldfusion, macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard

Has anyone found a way to install ColdFusion 8 on Snow Leopard? Is it possible?

Comment: what errors is it giving you?  i have CF8 installed but it carried over from my Leopard install when i upgraded.

Comment: oh also, sometimes the java version kickes out problems, did you try the 64 and 32 bit versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to successfully install it after clicking on the icon a few times.  you may have to wait for a period of time, i sat there for a bit and it opened asking to install rosetta, once  i installed rosetta the rest was normal.

I highly recommend rolling with mamp pro, it has made my life so much easier and it is pretty easy to integrate adobe coldfusion 9 into it

Answer (score -1):

Running into problems with my install... just found this, looks promising:

http://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2009/8/30/ColdFusion-8-Server-on-Snow-Leopard